# Instagram crawling with scrolling down...with python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler, instagram

```
total_link = []

temp = ['a']

total_num = 0

while driver.find_element_by_tag_name('div'):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    Divs=driver.find_element_by_tag_name('div').text


    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    my_titles = soup.select(
    'div._6d3hm > div._mck9w'
    )

    for title in my_titles:
        try:
            if title in temp:
                #print('중복')
                pass
            else:
                #print('중복이 아니다')
                link = str(title.a.get("href")) #주소를 가져와!
                total_link.append(link)
                #print(link)

        except:
            pass
    print("현재 모은 개수: " + str(len(total_link)))

    temp = my_titles
    time.sleep(2)
    if 'End of Results' in Divs:
        print('end')
        break
    else:
        continue
```

> Blockquote
>   Hello I was scraping instagram data with the tags in korean.
>       My code is consisted in the followings.

1. scroll down the page

   2. by using bs4 and requests, get their HTML
   3. locate to the point where the time log, picture src, text, tags, ID
   4. select them all, and crawl it.
   5. after it is done with the HTML that is on the page, scroll down
   6. do the same thing until the end

   By doing this, and using the codes of the people in this site, it seemed to work...
   but after few scrolls going down, at certain points, scroll stops with the error message showing

   '읽어드리지 못합니다' or in English 'Unable to read'

   Can I know the reason why the error pops up and how to solve the problem?
   I am using python and selenium
   thank you for your answer

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**Why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I changed a form of my question.

Comment: But core of the problem of mine is that is there any functions that instagram uses to block infinite scroll down...

Comment: you can refer this https://github.com/Aqua-4/auto-insta

Answer (score 0):

Instagram is trying to protect against malicious attacks, such as scraping or any other automated ways. It often occurs when you are trying to access to Instagram pages abnormally fast. So you have to set `time.sleep()` options more frequently or longer.